# Create bean in spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
<bean id="configuration" class="com.mypackage.util.Configuration" factory-method="getInstance">
<property name="path" value="${path.props.app.dev}"></property>
</bean>
```

Then I have the following in my class

```
Configuration.getInstance();
```

Whereas the spring application context is loaded in another class Factory like this

```
private Factory() {
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring.xml");
}
```

The problem is that before Factory class is accessed the context does not load and the configuration object gives null for path whereas when Factory is accessed and after that path property is accessed it gives the correct path.

Please tell me how to do it correctly? That is how can i get my member variable path with correct data without accessing Factory class.

Comment: More appropriately how can i load the context without accessing Factory class right when the application is loaded into the server?

Comment: It's now clear how are you using this code and what you want to achieve. Could you provide some context?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Spring WebMVC. There are 2 ways:

1. Putting you bean configurations to dispatcher config XML (`mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`)
2. Remain your `spring.xml`  and specify it in `web.xml`

   `<context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>spring.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>`

In both cases, you will no longer need a class like `Factory`. Besides, because of that Spring creates beans in singleton scope by default, you do not need to implement a `getInstance()` method for your `com.mypackage.util.Configuration` class.